# How does Equinox provide non locked jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I recently discovered that the plugin jars that are loaded by Eclipse do not retrieve a file lock. That is kind of surprising cause when i run a self made application the specific jars are locked and cannot be deleted. 
I am curious how this can be achieved. My first idea was that equinox copies the jars into a separate directory but that would take some time I guess. And i couldn't  find such directory

Hopefully someone has an idea...

Comment: copying the files to some temp location is indeed the common way of doing this.

Answer (score 4):

All OSGi Frameworks, including Equinox, have a so-called "storage" folder that contains the persistent state of the framework and bundles. By default the framework does indeed copy any installed bundles into that folder. In Equinox the default location of the storage folder is `configuration/org.eclipse.osgi`, however this can be overwritten by config.

There is also a special feature whereby a bundle can be installed without copying. This is done by prefixing the location URL with `reference:`. For example if you want to install the file `/home/neil/mybundle.jar` then you can call:

```
context.installBundle("reference:file:/home/neil/mybundle.jar");
```

Note that the reference URL scheme is not part of the OSGi specification, although it is supported by at least Equinox and Felix (and possibly other framework implementations).

Comment: I started eclipse and looked into that condiguration folder. Each bundle has its own id with its own folder. But i cannot see any jars in there...

Comment: That's because Eclipse installs most bundles using `reference:`. You will see some JARs in there for bundles containing `Bundle-ClassPath` entries. These seem to be under `bundles/<id>/1/.cp`. Anyway the framework can choose to store bundle contents in any format... it could even munge them into a single big binary blob if it wanted to.

Comment: But when you install them via reference then they should get a file lock on windows because the JVM will request one by first lowding of a class in that jar.

Comment: That might just be an implementation detail of a specific classloader. The OSGi classloader really only needs the bytes from inside the JAR, that can be done without a persistent lock.

Comment: I didn't knew that. So instead of using for example loadClass the OSGI ClassLoader handles the raw bytes from the jar by iterating over the entries (maybe with ZipFile or JarFile)?

Comment: I don't know. The OSGi specification certainly doesn't require anything like this. If you're interested in how particularly implementations do it, take a look at the source.